# Allow only one iPhone connection for my Bluetooth device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We have a BLE device that works like a Fitness band. I want to pair to only one iPhone from the band. Until the user unpairs from the phone or the user resets from the band, no other iPhone is allowed to connect to the band. As Apple is not allowed to have consistent unique identifiers for a phone, I am not finding to way to maintain a single connection.

Is someone know how The Health bands or rings work to have a single connection?

Comment: Have your read the [specs](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-pairing-part-1-pairing-feature-exchange/)?

Comment: If your device is paired/bonded to an iPhone then you will have a fixed identifier.  This is something you need to enforce in your device firmware by enabling encryption on at least one characteristic and no allowing additional bonding until the bonding table is empty